# Magento 2: How to get customer id

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, id

Can any one tell me how can I get the customer id whose order is being created by admin in admin panel, in file `/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form/account.phtml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$block->getCustomerId()
```

This should do it, let me know if you need any further assistance !

UPDATE:

In order to get the customer and retrive atributes you can do the following:

**SOLUTION USING OBJECT MANAGER**

```
$customerId = $block->getCustomerId();
if(isset($customerId))
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();    
    $customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);
    //here get the attributtes you need from $customer, for example
    $firstname = $customer->getData('firstname');
}
```

**SOLUTION USING CUSTOMER REPOSITORY:**

In your di.xml (Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml)

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Account"/>
```

Create the following file in (Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create)

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create;

class Account extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account
{
    public function getCustomer( $customerId)
    {
        try {
            return $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            /** If customer does not exist do nothing. */
        }
    }
}
?>
```

In your account.phtml:

```
$customerId = $block->getCustomerId();
if(isset($customerId))
{
    $customer = $block->getCustomer( $customerId);
    $firstname = $customer->getFirstName();
}

?>
```

Comment: How to get info in $order?? I mean it will show variable not define error

Comment: yeah my bad, give me 5 minutes ;)

Comment: Just updated the answer, it's $block->getCustomerId(). let me know it it's solved and don't forget to upvote/mark as answered :)

Comment: Yes this worked. Can you tell me is it possible to fetch the custom customer attribute here ??

Comment: yes, you jst need to make an instance and call the object manager, give me 5 minutes and I'll update my answer with that ;)

Comment: Updated, let me know if you any more help ;)

Comment: @Joao71 Direct use of ObjectManager `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();` is not recommended by Magento.

Comment: @Bhaumik1987 didn't know that, do you know why? Can you point me to the documentation about this issue so I can check it out please?

Comment: Please check it here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html#overview And also check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75010/why-i-should-not-use-object-manager-directly-in-magento2/75204#75204

Comment: "Direct use of the create function prevents type validation and type hinting that a factory class provides."

I don't see this as an issue in this particular case but I get it, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Nafisa just updated the answer with the two possible approaches in order to get the customer object. it's my true belief that in this case the is no harm in using ObjectManager but I'll leave that decision to you. Le me know if you need any further assistance ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get Customer ID in `/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form/account.phtml` using the below code:

```
<p>Customer Id:  <?= $this->getCustomerId() ?> </p>
<p>Customer Email: <?= $this->getQuote()->getCustomerEmail() ?></p>
```

Check the block `$block \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form\Account` as it gets in the same way.

Hope this helps!